# How to select some columns based on different data frames in R

Tags: r

I have three data frame as follows:

```html
df1<-read.table(text="id Group Location
1121 B O1
1141 M O4
1196 K O3
1166 P O9",header=TRUE)


df2<-read.table(text="id Cup Class Garden
1141 1 N V19
1166 3 N GH12
1121 4 Y O11
1146 2 N BP1",header=TRUE)


df3<-read.table(text="id Cup Class Garden
1166 3 N A11
1176 7 Y L12
1196 8 N N20
1120 4 N J0",header=TRUE)
```

As you can see df2 and df3 has two columns which are not seen in df1. I want to add values these columns to df1 using ids to get the following table:

```html
out<-read.table(text="id Group Location Class Garden
1121 B O1 Y O11
1141 M O4 N V19
1196 K O3 N N20
1166 P O9 N A11",header=TRUE)
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208951/discussion-on-question-by-user2343213-how-to-select-some-columns-based-on-differ).

Answer (score 0):

We can bind the data.frames with `bind_cols` (after converting the `factor` columns to `character`), remove the 'Cup' column, `filter` the rows where the 'id' from 'df1' are only present, grouped by 'id', `summarise` the rows to have a single row of non-NA element and slice the `last` row

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(df1, df2, df3) %>%
   select(-Cup) %>% 
   filter(id %in% df1$id) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ if(all(is.na(.))) NA 
        else 
           last(na.omit(.))) 
# A tibble: 4 x 5
# Groups:   id [4]
#     id Group Location Class Garden
#  <int> <fct> <fct>    <chr> <chr> 
#1  1121 B     O1       Y     O11   
#2  1141 M     O4       N     V19   
#3  1166 P     O9       N     A11   
#4  1196 K     O3       N     N20
```

#### data

```
df1[2:3] <- lapply(df1[2:3], as.character)
df2[3:4]  <- lapply(df2[3:4], as.character)
df3[3:4] <- lapply(df3[3:4], as.character)
```

Comment: Not interested in , sorry. it does not represent my outcome

Comment: @user2343213 your example shows the 'ids' not common in the datasets

Comment: What do you mean  ids are not common

Comment: I guess he means that the set of ids in `df1`and `df3`are not the same: the only ids shared by both dataframes are `1196`and `1166`

Comment: Thanks- These two ids are only important as they are available in df1 we want to get their values and add into outcome.

Comment: I got error with new codes... Column  'Cup must be length 1 ....

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to the `merge()` function. 
First you can bind the two dataframes together and then merge.

```
df4 <- rbind(df2, df3)

df1 <- merge(df1, df4, by = "id")
```

outputs

```
  id Group Location Cup Class Garden
1 1121     B       O1   4     Y    O11
2 1141     M       O4   1     N    V19
3 1166     P       O9   3     N   GH12
4 1166     P       O9   3     N    A11
5 1196     K       O3   8     N    N20
```

`by =` specifies what column to merge on and the columns are combined from the two inputs.

Comment: Mxblsdl, interesting, but CUP causes you did not get id 1196. Can we do better?

Comment: I see, `rbind` df2 and df3 together first. Then join the single dataframe with `merge()`

Comment: Thanks, but can we get  rid of   1166     P       O9   3     N   GH12

Comment: Sure you can remove that row, but I don't see why. Is there something in the data that indicates that observation should be removed? The ID from df1 matches two observations in df2 and df3. `subset(df1, Garden != "GH12")
`